# Running XUnit tests with a specific Traitname

Tags: xunit.net

Is it possible to run all Tests from one dll with a specific traitname, ignoring the traitvalue?

In my example i have gui and non gui tests and the gui tests offer different sites, which i run with jenkins.

`[Trait("GUI","MainPage")], [Trait("GUI","SecondPage")], [Trait("GUI","ThirdPage")]`

and now i want to run all Tests with "GUI" as a traitname, ignoring the value

```
xunit.console.x86.exe %MainDirectory%\Output\Release\Test_DMGuiTest.dll -trait "GUI=*"
```

Comment: Sorry, this functionality does not exist today. You could open a feature request for it at https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues